# How to use integration by parts in an example

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

We work on a filtered probability space. Let $\phi$ be an adapted predictable finite variation process, $S$ a cadlag submartingale, $T>0$ fixed, and $\tau,\sigma$ stopping times such that $0\leq\tau\leq\sigma\leq T$. How can we use integration by parts to show that the subsequent equality holds:

$(\phi\cdot(1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S))_T=(\phi1_{]\tau,\sigma]}\cdot S)_T + (\phi_{\tau}S_{\tau}-\phi_{\sigma}S_{\sigma})$

**What I received so far**: Using integration by parts, I get that

$(\phi\cdot(1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S))_T=(\phi1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S)_T-(1_{]\tau,\sigma]}S_{-}\cdot\phi)_T-[\phi,1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S]_T$.

How to proceed further?

**Edit**: In the first version of the question I wrote that $\phi$ is adapted, cadlag, FV. However, $\phi$ is adapted, *predictable*, FV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a direct method to get the equality what you want. Denote
$S^\sigma$ the stopped process of $S$ at $\sigma$, $(S^\sigma)_t=S_{t\wedge\sigma}$. Hence,
\begin{gather*}
 1_{[0,\sigma[}S=S^\sigma - S_{\sigma}1_{[\sigma,\infty[}\\
 \begin{aligned}
  \phi\cdot 1_{[0,\sigma[}S &=\phi \cdot S^\sigma - \phi\cdot (S_{\sigma}1_{[\sigma,\infty[})\\
  &=\phi 1_{[0,\sigma]}\cdot S-\phi_\sigma S_{\sigma}1_{[\sigma,\infty[}.
 \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
Therefore, using $1_{[\tau,\sigma[}=1_{[0,\sigma[}-1_{[0,\tau[} $  get
\begin{equation*}
 \phi\cdot 1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S=\phi 1_{]\tau,\sigma]}\cdot S
 +\phi_{\tau} S_{\tau}1_{[\tau,\infty[}-\phi_\sigma S_{\sigma}1_{[\sigma,\infty[}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I have a follow-up question: If $\eta$ is any $[0,T]$-valued stopping time (in particular, we do not assume that $\eta\leq\tau$ a.s., that $\tau\leq\eta\leq\sigma$ a.s., or that $\sigma\leq\eta$ a.s.), does it then holds that $(\phi\cdot(1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S))_{\eta} = ((\phi 1_{]\tau,\sigma]})\cdot S)_{\eta} + \phi_{\tau}S_{\tau} - \phi_{\sigma}S_{\sigma}$?

Comment: @hannah, Yes,  $(\phi\cdot (1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S))_{\eta}=((\phi 1_{]\tau,\sigma]})\cdot S)_{\eta}
+\phi_{\tau} S_{\tau}-\phi_\sigma S_{\sigma} $  holds if $\eta$ is any $[0,T]$-valued stopping time.

Comment: Thank you. What confuses me is that if we take for example $\eta=0$, then we receive that $0=0+\phi_{\tau}S_{\tau}-\phi_{\sigma}S_{\sigma}$, or equivalently that $\phi_{\sigma}S_{\sigma}=\phi_{\tau}S_{\tau} (*)$, which seems to be a too general statement to me. Is there a mistake in my argumentation, and if not, why does $(*)$ make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your mention. In fact, there are some confusion in my answer: $1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S$ not a cádlág process, how to define the integral $(\phi\cdot (1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S)) $, is the integral a cádlág process. Hence, the equality what you want may be just a interpretation of $(\phi\cdot (1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S)) $. I also rewrite the answer.

Comment: Please note that I just changed the assumption of $\phi$ being cadlag (this was not correct) to $\phi$ being predictable.

Comment: Why is $1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S$ not cadlag? $S$ is cadlag, so the question boils down to answering why  $1_{[\tau,\sigma[}$ is not cadlag.

Comment: Actually, the process $1_{[0,\sigma[}$ is cadlag (see p.6 in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-05265-5)). Thus, $1_{[\tau,\sigma[}=1_{[0,\sigma[}-1_{[0,\tau[}$ is cadlag as well.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. You are right, the $1_{[\tau,\sigma[}$ is cádlág. Now the equality is $\phi\cdot 1_{[\tau,\sigma[}S=\phi 1_{]\tau,\sigma]}\cdot S
 +\phi_{\tau} S_{\tau}1_{[\tau,\infty[}-\phi_\sigma S_{\sigma}1_{[\sigma,\infty[}$.